# Solr search is not working properly if the string contains a colon

Tags: search, solr

I have a field having the value `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen:`.

It is indexed in the solr like below

```
"tcngramm_X3b_nl_title":["ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen:"],
```

When I search for `ontwikkelingsdoelstelling`, it gives me the result.

But when I search for `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen` or `ontwikkelingsdoelstellinge` it does not give me the result.

I checked this in the solr admin UI as well using the `Query`.
http://example.com/solr/user-owned/select?debugQuery=on&q=tcngramm_X3b_nl_title%3Aontwikkelingsdoelstelling

What is the issue here?

```
Updated:
```

I have another field in the index, `tcngramm_X3b_nl_rendered_item` which has the value is a long descripton like

```
In uitvoering van de Duurzame Ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen
```

This is a part of the value.

If I search in this field `tcngramm_X3b_nl_rendered_item`, `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen`, it also gives me no results

Here it works without the last two characters `en`
[image]

And here it does not work with the actual word.

[image]

This is the field type
[image]

Comment: What is the field definition for the field you're searching against? (i.e. the index and query analyzer for that field)?

Comment: From which screen can I get these info?

Comment: It's in your schema file, but can also been seen in the last screenshot you've included - you have to expand the TokenizerChain values. You can also see exactly how your terms are processed under the Analysis menu option, which should indicate _why_ these terms doesn't match as you expect them to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The issue was in the solr config files.

It was like this:

```
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="accents_und.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_und.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords_und.txt" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="accents_und.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You see the `maxGramSize` is 25 and `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen` has 27 characters. So increasing the value of that attribute fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /
```

To escape these character use the `\` before the character. For example to search for `(1+1):2` use the query:

```
\(1\+1\)\:2
```

Comment: I am searching for `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen` without the colon. And it gives me no results. and when you remove the last two characters `en` and search fo `ontwikkelingsdoelstelling`, the search works fine.

Comment: Also if I search for the full text including the colon `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen:`, it also works fine.

Comment: Is the current issue which you mentioned in the main question resolved for you?

Comment: No, It didn't resolve. The main question is also about the search without `en`

Comment: Which word is been index and how is it indexed, the query result depends on it. If you are indexing ontwikkelingsdoelstelling without transforming the text then it will work for the search ontwikkelingsdoelstelling.

Comment: It is index as `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen:` but the search works for `ontwikkelingsdoelstelling` and not for `ontwikkelingsdoelstellingen`

Comment: what is the field type applied for it...Did you checked the same on admin UI page?

Comment: Yes I checked on admin UI as well. I will post a screenshot in the question. The field type is `text_ngram`

Comment: Please check from the analysis page. How the test is analysed after appying different tokenisers and filters

Comment: What should I show you from that page?

Comment: You need not have to show anything....But you yourself can analyse...how the text is analyzed while indexing and how is the analyzed while quering and based on the analysis you can understand what is wrong while performing the search and can decide what is need to be done with tokeniser and filter...Do you want to change any according to your requirements?